# Autonumber in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: dataextensions, form, marketing-cloud

I am currently building a smartcapture form. It is capturing new contacts to be stored in a data extension in marketing cloud. It takes their name, email address etc. I also want it to assign them a unique number as a secondary personal id (email address is used as primary key and subscriber key).

Is there a way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no auto-numbering in SFMC.

You have a few options:

You can assign them a GUID with the [**NewID()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) SQL function in a [**Query Activity**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/).

You can reference the hidden [**_CustomObjectKey**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_and_data_relationships/) column in a Data Extension.  It's a unique number assigned to each row.  It is not always sequential and does not start at 1.

You can use a ranking function in SQL to assign a number to each row:

```
select
  x.emailaddress
, x.insertDate
, x.idNum
FROM (
 select
    s.emailaddress
  , s.insertDate 
  , row_number() over (order by s.insertDate desc) idNum
  from signupform s
) x
```

Either way, you'll need to run a Query Activity on your captured data to populate it.

Comment: Can you update your link for the _CustomObjectKey ... I can't find anything related on the provided resource.

Comment: I'm not seeing a good link for it.  Here are a few references:  https://success.salesforce.com/search?keywords=_CustomObjectKey